# Confused about httpd, nginx and Vesta CP

Tags: apache, curl, nginx, vesta

I have a freshly installed CentOS on a VPS with Vesta CP.

Vesta CP is accessible on port 8083

netstat reveals:

nginx is listening on ports 8083 and 80

httpd is listening on port 8080

httpd.conf has no virtual hosts defined

nginx.conf has all my sites defined

To see what apache and nginx are doing I have devised this test:

curl http://example.com

curl http://example.com:8083

I do the above with both httpd and nginx running, with both stopped and with one or the other running. 4 tests in all.

For my normal site to load BOTH httpd and nginx must be running. If either is stopped I get the error "couldn't connect to host".

However doing a curl on port 8083 ALWAYS returns an html stub even when nginx and httpd are BOTH stopped.

Questions:

1) Why do I need apache at all (it uses up a lot of memory) and how can I run nginx exclusively?

2) What is serving port 8083 since it returns an html stub even when nginx is stopped?

All and any comments appreciated.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I have now set up the site using nginx exclusively. It is a membership site with a lot of user-specific dynamic content, and it is blazingly fast. I use VestaCP as my control panel. When you set up Vesta, you can choose from a number of installation scripts. nginx is one of the options.

Once VestaCP is installed, you can create web sites as you would in any control panel. One of the templates is for WordPress. I have read that you need Apache to run WordPress but this is false.

nginx does not use .htaccess. Everything must be done in the config file. This is more work but it is worth it IMHO. I have tested the site at a rate of 1.5 million pages per day. I don't think I could do that with Apache on 512Mb. For now, I am impressed with nginx.

To be clear, I did not install Apache at all. All pages static and dynamic are served by nginx.

```
Details
Hosting: Digital Ocean
Server memory: 512Mb
OS: CentOS
Web Server: nginx
PHP processor: php-fpm
PHP version: 7
DataBase: MySQL (not mariadb which is default on CentOS)
Control Panel: VestaCP
IDE: Eclipse
Debugger: XDebug
```

If you are building a high-volume WordPress site for your client, I highly recommend this config.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx serves static files (images, css, html etc.) really fast and efficient and passes php and .htaccess requests to apache for processing

Apache serves php and .htaccess (most cms site like wordpress needs it for rewrite) and if you throw in a php opcode cache like zend opcache or xcache it should serve php even faster

Nginx + Apache with php opcache = performance and server resource efficiency

(Answer taken from [here](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=5407#p14082))

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. I have since resolved this and should have answered my own question, my bad. See answer, below...